# What are the possible causes for a camera not saving images with a new lens?

Tags: equipment-damage

I've just received a new used lens (75-300 Canon) for my 1100D, but putting it on the camera and trying to shoot:

- it doesn't save anything
- the screen remains black
- the led remains switched on
  points 2 and 3 persist even after restarting.

What's possibly happened? I don't have any guarantee or so, there isn't the box. And the lens looks like new.

Comment: which leds are you talking about? can you be more precise?

Comment: Have you tried a different lens on it to see if it does the same thing?

Comment: the led that says to you when the photo is being saved. with the previous objective everything works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guesses:

- Your "new used" lens is not correctly mounted or is defective, therefore producing a bad electric connection, therefore preventing the camera from correctly turning on.
- Is your battery ok? Can you try turning your camera on with a someone else's battery? Maybe your battery died the same time you switched to the new lens.

Does your camera turn on without the lens?

Comment: The camera works perfectly without the objective, so it is defective, right?

Comment: Probably it is. You can try mounting the objective on a different camera. If it doesn't work too, it's defective for sure. You can them try to repair it or get your money back (if you still can!)